# StoreOnce 3540 System Library Offline

Tags: backup

I have a StoreOnce 3540 System.
In VTL/Libraries, i have one as offline.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cr50.png)

How can i turn it online?

Thanks.